Best solution? - NYC apartment mod, installing a mount between two drywall supports
I need to install a wooden beam between two pieces of drywall to support a leverage-based chin-up bar. What is the best way to go about this?
It’s possible one of the sides, but probably not both, have a stud behind it. The surfaces may not be perfectly parallel to each other.
I’m not sure I see how to be able to sturdily screw in a solid beam to both sides of a space.
The beam cannot be rounded, because then the leverage-based chin-up bar would slide off, since it too has corners to its piece that rests on leverage.
The span is 31.5” wide. The thinner side is a support that’s 4.25” wide. And I’m assuming any mounting would be best to go into the center of it.
For all intents and purposes, the super of the apartment building can’t be asked nor can a professional be hired.

What does leverage-based mean?    What are "pieces of drywall"?  Are you saying you want to hang a chinup bar between two finished hollow stud walls that are 31.5" apart?    Do you know if the studs are metal or wood?  Do you know their spacing?  Why do you nee a beam?  Why not just ask how to attach a metal bar to these walls?

An easy way to hang a chinup bar between two finished stud walls 31.5 inches apart where the studs do not align is: Screw 2x4s flat against the two walls, at the same height, using 3 studs each and appropriate screws for your studs.  Get a 31.5 inch metal bar e.g. a used barbell cut to size.  In the middle of each 2x4 cut a round notch the size of the bar, and rest the bar in it.  Do chinups.

Yes, if there's not a stud directly opposite on a wall, you need to span studs with something (and attach to those somethings) so both sides are attached to studs.
